# How to customize the context menu in the solution explorer for a specific project type?

Tags: vsix, vspackage

**Description**

---

I have developed a Visual Studio extension (VSPackage) which adds a new Project Type to Visual Studio (using [CPS Project System](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem)). I also have added some Commands to the VSPackage.

When right clicking on my Project Node in the Solution Explorer, I want to have a customized context menu to appear.

**Example**

---

For example: in the screen shot below, I want to get rid of the Build command and add a custom command (e.x. `mycommand`).

[image]

**I tried..**

---

Setting the `Parent` of my custom command to `IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE`.

**Question**

---

- When I create a new Custom Project Type, How to create a new Context Menu for my Project Nodes in the Solution Explorer?
- How to remove/add Commands to the Context Menu only for the Custom Projects:
  If I have a `C#` project, the context menu should be the default one, if I add a `MyProjectType` project, I want to see a different context menu when right clicking on the Project Node in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: @DoronG not really

Answer (score 4):

You were close with the `IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE` parent.

Here is how I achieved it in my [FluentMigratorRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamirBoulema.FluentMigratorRunner) extension, which only shows its context menu item for a project if it has a reference to the FluentMigrator NuGet package.

**Step 1:** Add a submenu to the context menu

```
<Menus>
  <Menu guid="guidCmdSet" id="packageMenu" priority="0x0300" type="Menu">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_CTXT_PROJECT_BUILD" />
    <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>DefaultInvisible</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>CPSProject</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>CPSProject</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Menu>
```

Note the added special `CommandFlag` elements.

**Step 2:** Add a group to the menu

```
<Groups>  
  <Group guid="guidCmdSet" id="packageMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="packageMenu" />
  </Group>    
</Groups>
```

**Step 3:** Add a button

```
  <Button guid="guidCmdSet" id="specialBuildActionId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="packageMenuGroup" />
    <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Special build</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
```

**Step 4:** Add the menu in your *Package.cs

```
protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InitializeAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
{
    // Initialize the Fluent Migrator Menu, should only be visible for projects with FluentMigrator reference
    var mcs = await GetServiceAsync(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
    var menuCommandId = new CommandID(packageCmdSetGuidString, 0x1010);
    var menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(null, menuCommandId);
    menuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += MenuItem_BeforeQueryStatus;

    mcs.AddCommand(menuItem);
}

private void MenuItem_BeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    ((OleMenuCommand)sender).Visible = ???;
```

Note the added `BeforeQueryStatus` eventhandler.

In that eventhandler you can check the type of the project and return a boolean controlling if the extra context menu should be shown yes or no

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about removing the existing `Build` menu item... but as for having context menu items appear *only* when right-clicking on your custom project type, `<VisibilityConstraints>` might help:

*(Excerpt from an [example usage](https://github.com/madskristensen/VisibilityConstraintsSample)):*

> Often a package is being loaded to run a `BeforeQueryStatus` method for a button to determine its visibility. With `<VisibilityConstraints>` we can determine the visibility of a button without running `BeforeQueryStatus` and therefore don't need to load the package before the user clicks the button.

I've only ever used this strategy to show menu items for specific *file* types, but there are also some [term types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-rule-based-ui-context-for-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022#term-types) related to *projects* that might be more useful for this scenario.